# Apply force to bottom of object given rotation

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

I have a box and I want to apply a force in the direction that the bottom of the box is facing, given any Pitch, Roll, or Yaw rotation. At a resting point where pitch, roll, and yaw are 0, I know the downward force would be: x = 0, y = 0, z = -n, as the box is laying flat.

I also have the box's quaternion (qx, qy, qz, qw) available if that is helpful.

Here is a visual example showing my question:

[A box with a pitch of 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAJPSm.png)

[image]

[A box with a pitch of 90](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uQWym.png)

[image]

How can I get this force using the objects rotation?

Comment: @mvw The force will be applied in a loop, so as the rotation changes, the direction of the force needs to change with it to always be applied to the top of the box. At any given time I need to be able to get the direction the force needs to be in using the current rotation

Comment: @mvw you are correct, sorry for my misuse of the terms!

Comment: @mvw I am looking to get the X, Y, and Z direction of force (in my particular case, Z is less necessary)

Comment: Is there no way to calculate the force from the present orientation alone? I don't think that's what I'm trying to find. The goal is the simulated gravity relative to the objects orientation.

Comment: @mvw I believe my problem is much for simple than your interpretation of it. Lets just say for example my box's current orientation is: Pitch=90, Roll=10, Yaw=20. There is 0 force presently on the object (I need to calculate it and apply it myself!). Using that orientation information, can I calculate what the force needs to be to push on the top of the object. I also have the box's quaternion available if that is helpful.

Comment: You start with your first image where the force is $F=(0,0,-\lVert F\rVert)$. Then you apply the appropriate rotation matrices $R_P$, $R_R$, $R_Y$ (each parameterized with a suitable form of your parameter) to that vector: $F' = R_Y R_R R_P F$. You have to work out the details for yourself, have a look at the definition of [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) and how your parameters are defined.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded my search terms to finding a force direction from a quaternion and was able to find an excellent [answer](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/56471-extracting-direction-vectors-from-quaternion/) by a user named Dobbs:

> **forward vector**:
>
> x = 2 * (x*z + w*y)
>
> y = 2 * (y*z - w*x)
>
> z = 1 - 2 * (x*x + y*y)
>
> **up vector**:
>
> x = 2 * (x*y - w*z)
>
> y = 1 - 2 * (x*x + z*z)
>
> z = 2 * (y*z + w*x)
>
> **left vector**:
>
> x = 1 - 2 * (y*y + z*z)
>
> y = 2 * (x*y + w*z)
>
> z = 2 * (x*z - w*y)

Using the "forward vector" with a negative magnitude I was able to apply a constant force onto the top of my object, no matter the orientation.